# Why is the actual value of an axis position different than the derived value in MATLAB suplot figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

I've got a figure with two subplots being displayed. I want to get the axis position of each plot so I am using the figure's children information:

```
 subplot(211)
 % Plot stuff here
 ...
 subplot(212)
 % Plot stuff here 
 ...

 % Get Axes Position information
 f =gcf;
 % Bottom Plot Axis
 disp(f.Children(2).Position)
 % Top Plot Axis
 disp(f.Children(4).Position)
```

The console displays:

```
 Bottom plot:
     0.1300    0.1100    0.7750    0.3412

 Top plot:
     0.1300    0.5838    0.7750    0.3412
```

This seems correct given all else. When I run the plot to generate the figure and then inspect the axes' information via 'Show Plot Tools and Dock Figure->Inspector: matlab.graphics.axis.Axes' option the width value for each axis's position is not 0.7750. The other position values are as listed but the width is different for both the top and bottom plots. The top becomes [0.13 0.5838 0.682 0.341] and the bottom becomes [0.13 0.11 0.67 0.341].

Does anyone know why this is and how to get the "real" position values and not the incorrect displayed/printed ones?

Useful info: MATLAB R2014b

EDIT UPDATE:
Here is a MWE that produces the behavior.

```
clear all; close all; clc; 
figure; 

subplot(211)
hold on

x1 = [ -1 -0.998 -0.996 -0.994 -0.992];
y = [0.000324249267578125 -0.000370025634765625 -3.4332275390625e-005 -0.000186920166015625 -0.000110626220703125];
plot(x1, y, '-', 'MarkerSize', 10) 

set(gca, 'FontName', 'Interstate-Light', 'FontSize', 7)
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', [])
set(gca, 'XLabel', [])
grid on
ylabel('Frequency Error (Hz)', 'FontName', 'Interstate-Bold')
legend({'FE'}, 'Location', 'NorthEastOutside', 'FontName', 'Interstate-Light', 'Box', 'off')

subplot(212)
hold on
x1 = [ -1 -0.998 -0.996 -0.994 -0.992];
y = [-0.010614013299346 -0.0417663566768169 0.0235949698835611 -0.0502893067896366 0.0316442884504795];
plot(x1, y, '-', 'MarkerSize', 10) 

% Overide X-axis ticks to align with data
XTick = unique(x1);

grid on;
xlabel('Time (s)', 'FontName', 'Interstate-Bold')
ylabel('Frequency Error (Hz)', 'FontName', 'Interstate-Bold')
set(gca, 'FontName', 'Interstate-Light', 'FontSize', 7)
legend({'RFE'}, 'Location', 'NorthEastOutside', 'FontName', 'Interstate-Light', 'Box', 'off')

% Get figure object
f = gcf;
% Set fontsize to 16 for readability in final pdf
set(findall(f, '-property','FontSize'),'FontSize',16)
f.PaperUnits = 'inches';
f.PaperPosition = [0 0 20 14];
f.PaperPositionMode = 'manual'; 

% Get axis position info
disp('Second plot:')
disp(f.Children(2).Position)
disp('First Plot:')
disp(f.Children(4).Position)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with the code and steps provided.

Comment: Doesn't docking the figure change the geometry of the window? Or that shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: @AndrasDeak the default units of the axes generated by `subplot` are `Normalized` and should not change with the geometry of the window.

Comment: @excaza emphasis on the "should not"?:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak if you can show that this happens, feel free.

Comment: @excaza, no-no, sorry, I was just wondering whether this was the actual standard behaviour, or just common sense. The latter is often missing from matlab. *And* I just realized that this is HG2.

Comment: @AndrasDeak unknown, I can't reproduce in R2013b either.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with `R2012b` and I've been able to reproduce the problem and also (almost) been able to understand what's happening.

I do not know if it is also  applicable to more "recent" versin of MatLab.

The problem seems related to the `default` configuration of the window `Show Plot Tools and Dock Figure`

[image]

With this configuration, actually the `position` of the two axes (read in the `Property editor` are different with respect to the "original ones:

```
original pos ax 1=  [0.1300    0.5838    0.7750    0.3412]
new pos ax1=[0.1300    0.629     0.7750    0.268 ]
```

Nevertheless, if you `minimize` the `Property editor` tab and look at the `Position` of the two axes, they are restored to the "original" one values.

You can, the "slide up" the tab and the `position` still remain the "original onne.

I'do not know if this is actually an answer to you question; what I can say is that the right position `position` are the "original" ones.

It could be a sort of bug in the visualization in the default configuratin od the `Show Plot Tools and Dock Figure` window.

Hope this helps.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not just that the visualization looks wonky but that when I go into the inspector for each axis the position values are not the ones displayed in the console. Also, when I save the figure as a png it displays with the 'different' position values and not the console printed out values. Still can't fix.